# Expect dynamic input from bash

Tags: bash, expect

Assume the following `bash` script, `questions.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, who are you?"
read REPLY
```

and the following `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ./questions.sh # start our script using spawn command
expect "Hello, who are you?\r"
send -- "Im Adam\r"
```

The expect script acts as an answering robot to the shell script. Now assume that that I need to generate some answers dynamically. For instance, let's say that I want to feed the output of another shell script (`answers.sh`) as an answer. How would I have to modify the `expect` script? I tried the following but does not seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ./questions.sh # start our script using spawn command
expect "Hello, who are you?\r"
send ./answers.sh
```

Comment: You don't even need expect for this: `./answers.sh | ./questions.sh`

Comment: @glennjackman not if questions.sh has to be executed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ./questions.sh # start our script using spawn command
expect "Hello, who are you?\r"
set answer [exec ./answer.sh]
send $answer
```